# React Native error when use command "react-native run-android"

Tags: android, react-native

When I try to run the command w on my terminal, always find errors in the image below.

My SDK Path : E:\SOFTWARE\SDKAndroid

Have I missed something in the setting SDK on my computer? Please help...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a Java installation issue (maybe only missing an environment variable pointing to the JDK?). Try reinstalling Java. Also, I'd run react-native with the `--stacktrace` or `--debug` as suggested by the command output in order to understand exactly what's going on.